# How should I write an array insert to store two named columns like an sql query creates?

Tags: ruby, postgresql

I have a setup table of about 30 items, all of which are used in various locations.  I make one call for some of the data in the application controller, and thought that I might save some cpu cycles and build some of the collection_select sql calls as arrays built from the first pass into the setup table.

I have one collection that requires that I pass two values from the db.

I can create an array that only passes a single column to a collection_select.  I hit a wall when I try to pass two columns of data.  Here is the array built by an sql call, with the resulting data.

```
@myscosts = Setmeup.find_by_sql("select (t_is || '--' || description) as shipr, description::float as cost  from setmeups where active is true and g_is = 'Ship' order by t_is, srby;")

        shipr         | cost
----------------------+------
FedEx_Large--17.00   |   17
FedEx_Medium--7.00   |    7
 FedEx_Small--5.00    |    5
 Self_Delivery--1.00  |    1
 USPS_2d_Large--9.00  |    9
 USPS_2d_Medium--5.00 |    5
 USPS_2d_Small--3.00  |    3
(7 rows)
```

In the application controller I have this code:

```
@setups = Setmeup.find_by_sql("select g_is, t_is, srby, description from setmeups where active = 'true' order by g_is, srby;")
#    puts @setups.class

  @setups.each do |f|
    @title = "#{f.description}" if "#{f.g_is}" == "App"  && "#{f.t_is}" == "Title"
(more code here, the next stanza works for a collection)

if f.t_is == 'Process' then
  @steps << "#{f.srby} - #{f.description}"
end

(I can not find the right way to make this one work.)
if "#{f.g_is}" == 'Ship' then
  @shpr = "#{f.t_is} -- #{f.description}"
  @cst = "#{f.description}".to_f
  @myscosts << "[#{@cst},  #{@shpr} ]"
end
(results of above in log..)
myscosts == ["[5.0,  FedEx_Small -- 5.00]", "[3.0,  USPS_2d_Small -- 3.00]", "[1.0,  Self_Delivery -- 1.00]", "[5.0,  USPS_2d_Medium -- 5.00]", "[7.0,  FedEx_Medium -- 7.00]", "[9.0,  USPS_2d_Large -- 9.00]", "[17.0,  FedEx_Large -- 17.00]"]
```

Rails validation step throws error because the value passed:
"shipping_quoted"=>"[\"5.0\", \"FedEx_Small -- 5.00\"]" is not a number.

This is passed when the sql query creates the array:
    "shipping_quoted"=>"5.0"

The data in the above example does not constitute all of the setup variables and options.  Below is the method within the program to use the collection with the array '@myscosts' created by a direct sql query:

```
<%= form.label :shipping_quoted %>
<%= form.collection_select :shipping_quoted, @myscosts, :cost, :shipr %>
```

This is the collection_select I am having trouble dynamically creating an array that mimics the sql query result.  Here is an example of a collection_select (with only one value passing) that I am able to get to work (but I do not understand how :to_s acts as an alias):

```
<%= form.label :step %>
<%= form.collection_select :step, @steps, :to_s, :to_s %>
```

My hope is to somehow have someone help me understand how to do something like this:
    (in a model or controller)

```
@a1 = sql("select * from xytable";)  # where @a1[0..n].y = 'Y' 

 @a1.each do |k|
   if k.y != 'Y'
     @a2 << "#{k}"  # or "#{k.inspect}"
   end
 end
```

Such that array @a2 has the same class type, structure and key value pairs as array @a1.  I could then use @a2 in a collection like the sql array generated as @myscosts.

Thanks for your response, I hope I have answered your questions with this additional data.

Comment: If this is your actual data set, do you really need to use SQL to create the array? Does the data change ever/often? Also, where is the code that is trying to persist the data to the DB?